# Not able to fetch the URL / location of the pop-up window

Tags: javascript, url, window, location, popupwindow

Is there a way to fetch the URL / Location of the pop-up window?

CODE:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
   function openWin()
   {
      myWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','','width=200,height=100');
      console.debug(myWindow.location.href);
      console.debug(window.location.href);
   }
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The first console prints `about:blank`

While the second console prints the URL of the current page(i.e URL of the above code, it does not print the URL of the pop-up window)

Why isn't the first console printing the location (i.e http://www.google.com) ?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because browser security prevents you from getting the URL from any window that's not on the same domain as your script. So, if your code was running on example.com, you'd only be able to get the URL of any window that was also on example.com.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hg3 says, you cannot access `location.href` for `myWindow`. `window.open` returns an empty `DOMWindow`.

However, you can overwrite `window.open` and maintain a simple array of all the windows you have opened.

```
//override window.open
var windows = [];
window._open = window.open;
window.open = function(url, name, params){
    windows.push(name, url);
    return window._open(url, name, params)
}
//function return href by name
function hrefByName(name) {
    var index=(windows.indexOf(name));
    return (index>-1) ? windows[index+1] : 'undefined';
}

//modified openWin function
function openWin(url, name) {
    var params='width=200,height=100';
    window.open(url, name, params);
    //test, ouput current url and the windows array
    console.log(hrefByName(name));
    console.log(windows);
}
```

test markup :

```
<input type="button" value="google" onclick="openWin('http://google.com', 'google')" />
<input type="button" value="bing" onclick="openWin('http://bing.com', 'bing')" />
<input type="button" value="stackoverflow" onclick="openWin('http://stackoverflow.com', 'stackoverflow')" />
```

Of course, I guess you have a setup with dynamically generated URL's - just build random names or pass an unique number as name.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. But I am looking out for a way to fetch the URL of the window. Suppose in the example that you posted, I click on 'google' button. The google window opens. Now I search something in google and the URL for that window will change. Now how do I fetch that URL?

Comment: @Anish Nair, you are not allowed to do that due to security in browsers. You can fetch href's from child windows opened by you only if they share the same origin as the "parent"-window. What you want is in fact a kind of tracker that can spy on every browserwindow or tab. The only way I can see how you can accomplish that is by a desktop app installed locally that enumaretes all browser processes and get their URL's / hrefs.